# Слово "безлепица"

Tags: этимология, лексика

Здравствуйте!
Слышала такое слово: "безлепица". Есть ли оно в русском языке и чем по смыслу отличается от "нелепицы"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

НЕЛЕПЫЙ – это некрасивый, таково изначальное значение этого слова, а дословно: без румян и красок, без «лепки». Общеславянская основа lepyi – красивый, хороший. Семантически «лепый» сходно со словами «смазливый, писаный».

Затем значение слова изменялось: некрасивый, нескладный, потом  неразумный. В современном значении неразумность стала основным значением, а красота отошла на второй план. НЕЛЕПЫЙ 1. Лишённый здравого смысла, разумных оснований; бессмысленный.  2.Нескладный, неуклюжий.

Итак, БЕЗЛѢПИЦ|А - то, что не подобает, не следует делать . Со временем слово изменило свою форму, теперь это НЕЛЕПОСТЬ (также НЕЛЕПИЦА – разговорный вариант). Приставка НЕ отрицает наличие признака: «нелепый» –  это не являющийся «лепым»,  в то время как приставка БЕЗ  часто усиливает значение (сравнить: неумный и безумный).

Теперь слова «безлепица» нет в словаре, но у Даля оно еще присутствует: БЕЗЛЕПИЦА -  нелепица, бессмыслица || безвкусие в постройке, наряде, убранстве и пр.  Поэтому «безлепицу»  можно встретить только в старых текстах (или в исторической литературе):

«С места выходила какая-то безлепица: как это так – пришел с покойным? Не ходят покойники! Действительно, чего доброго, за сумасшедшего примут! (М. Булгаков).

Словно лепится сурепица, На обрушенный забор, Жизни сонная безлепица  Отуманила мой взор. Словно мальчик, быстро пчёлами Весь облепленный, кричит, — Стонет сердце под уколами Злых и мелочных обид (Ф. Соллогуб).